# javafx project that has an fxml document that won't let me inject a label into my controller

Tags: eclipse, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder, injectable

I created a JavaFX project. Here is what it looks like:

[image: JavaFX project]
In SceneBuilder I created a `BorderPane` with one label with the id `label`.
In my `SampleController` I use this Label named `label`:

```
Label label;
public SampleController() {
    label.setText("hi");
}
```

If I remove `label.setText("hi");` the code works fine but when the code is there I get the following error. 
It is very long, here is a part of it.

> javafx.fxml.LoadException:

I think that is the most important part.
I can however add buttons and their actions and it still works fine.
now i added.

```
@FXML
private Pane taskPane;
private void initialize() {
        System.out.println(taskPane.getWidth());
    }
```

i did the same thing as the label with a pane and i get a
null pointer exception.

Comment: Hey there, I suggest you add the full stacktrace in there, because the most important thing is not just the exception name, but also where it occurs. In particular there should be a "Caused by"-block somewhere telling you what the problem is. Sadly I am not a JavaFX-expert and thus cannot help you, but I guess with a full stacktrace your odds of receiving a helpful answer are higher.

Comment: If buttons and there actions work fine, controller definition in the controller should be ok. Next, what you want to look at is the `fx:id` of the Label. If you can post the fxml in the question, it would help to resolve your query faster.

Answer (score 0):

When the fxml is loaded the controller instance is created before `FXMLLoader` injects objects into the fields of the controller. Since you're trying to access the `Label` in the constructor invoked during the contollers creation this results in a `NullPointerException`.

Move the initialisation of the `Label` to the `initialize` method. This method is invoked by `FXMLLoader` just before returning from the `load` method, i.e. after injecting the fields:

```
@FXML
Label label;
public SampleController() {}

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    label.setText("hi");
}
```

Simply setting the `text` property of a label can be done from the fxml too of course...

Comment: now when i add a pane and try to do get or set the pane I get a null pointer exception.